# Telegram bot questions

Tags: telegram-bot

User1 has a Telegram account and created the Telegram bot Bot1.
User2 has a Telegram account.

How User 2 can work with Bot1? i.e. in teh same way as User1 does it: send commands etc.

How Bot1 can send messages to User2? I.e. report about smth etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean work with BotFather? No.
Each user can access to its own bots using BotFather and you can't access other bots from another accounts. But if you mean work with tokens, then yes you can work with bots that you have their tokens.
Getting last updates from telegram: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates 
NodeJS library: https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api

Comment: Yes, something like this. What I want: to send commands to User1's bot1 from Telegram app (User1) and from telephone with (User2). My app bot needs to check updates from 2 accounts, but how?

Comment: You just need to call getUpdates function of Telegram bot API to get last updates or set webhooks. But i suggest you to use a library for your puporse. I've added links to the answer.https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

Answer (score 1):

Okay let's break your questions into parts:

1. How User 2 can work with Bot1?
   When you say `work with` its kind of relative. There are two assumptions I can 
   come up with: 
   (I). It means that User2 wants to send commands from his 
   telegram app on his mobile device to bot1(bot1 was made by User1), in this 
   case anyone can send messages (any form of text) and [commands](https://core.telegram.org/bots#commands) (like 
   `/showusers`) to any bot even though they were not its creator. Also just a 
   side note this is from the [telegram bot docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans)

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first. People can use telegram.me/ links or username search to find your bot.

(II). On the other hand `work with` can mean that I can program how bot1 
    interacts with its users, e.g if a user sends `/ping` to the bot reply with a 
    message pong. In this case only User1 can work with bot1 because he has the 
    bot token. However if User1 gives his Bot token(its like your credit card 
    details) to User2 then User2 can program that bot to do anything he wants.

So to answer your question, if you mean my first assumption then User2 only needs telegram installed and the name of Bot1 but if you mean assumption 2 then User2 needs the bot token from User1 to work with it.

2. How Bot1 can send messages to User2? Every user has a unique chatid that telegram sends to you the first time someone clicks the start button of your bot(actually they send the chatid every time a person uses your bot). All you need to do is to store this chatid in a database or something and then when you want to send the person a message you indicate the chat id. Read about the [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method made available by the API to better understand how to use it.